# Status bar is not preview in PhoneGap iOS plugin

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I have created a PhoneGap project and bind iOS platform to it,

Previously their is no StatusBar . So i installed a plugin to it called,
 **"org.apache.cordova.statusbar"**

This looks great and status bar appeared in html page , But if try to load status bar in to another iOS plugin , it doesn't appear  properly. It does in portraide mode. but not the landscape

This happens only in iOS 8 but not in iOS 7

Comment: Are you testing this on your device? And what do you mean with "load status bar in to another ios plugin"?

Comment: yes iphone 6 , i have created feature which opens up a camera, this is a separate native plugin

Comment: The camera of ios7 and ios8 does not show the statusbar. This is native. So i don´t think that you can show the status bar while taking a picture.

Comment: This is a problem. It is not related to camera. In my app I am not using camera and still the status bar is not displaying in landscape mode. Instead status bar only blank space at the top area is displayed.@m1crdy

Comment: @Mr.G You can refer this link. http://shazronatadobe.wordpress.com/2014/09/18/cordova-ios-and-ios-8/   May be you can get some direction.

Answer (score 0):

You have to update status bar pulgin that is

cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap-build/StatusBarPlugin.git

Or else u can made some code changes according to this article.
 http://ciesielskipiotr.com/status-bar-troubles/